# How to add and save non model properties to Django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model in django like the following.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

  def setContactInfoProperty(key, value):
    setattr(self.contactInfo, key, value)
    self.contactInfo.save()

  def getContactInfoProperty(key):
    return getattr(self.contactInfo, key)

  @phone.setter
  def phone(self, value):
    self.setContactInfoProperty('phone',value)

  def phone(self):
    return self.getContactInfoProperty('phone')

class ContactInfo(models.Model):
  phone = models.IntegerField()
  employee = models.OneToOneField('Employee', related_name='contactinfo')
```

The setter for Phone is kept in Employee model for legacy reasons. I have a django form for Employee now and i want to add phone as well to it. So i thought of adding the phone attribute to EmployeeForm.

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    fields = ['name', 'phone']
```

But when i save the form, phone is not saved. How can i set the phone number from EmployeeForm?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That's a weird setup you have. If you add fields like that, it might cause the `ModelForm` to not pickup the field. Why not using django migration to add new fields?

Comment: Yes, i have added migration but i don't want to directly write to ContactInfo. This is because of legacy reasons and validations present in phone.setter().

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your model setup would make the `EmployeeForm` recognize the `phone` field, so you need to save it manually:

```
# in views.py
if employee_form.is_valid():
    new_employee = employee_form.save(commit=False)
    new_employee.phone = employee_form.cleaned_data['phone']
    new_employee.save()
```